# Is there a way to convert audio files to byte array in android studio

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to store an audio file that is picked by the user from his own music player into sqlite database and I want to know is there a way to convert audio files to byte array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String path = ""; // Audio File path
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path); 
byte[] arr = readByte(inputStream);

Log.d("byte: ", "" + Arrays.toString(arr));
```

**or**

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[0xFFFF];
    for (int len = is.read(buffer); len != -1; len = is.read(buffer)) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    return os.toByteArray();
}

try {
    String path = ""; // Audio File path
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
    byte[] myByteArray = getBytesFromInputStream(inputStream);
    // ...
} catch(IOException e) {
    // Handle error...
}
```

Comment: Is there a readByte function for byte array?

Comment: There is no method on a byte array to read bytes, but if you are having trouble using this function, use the one I put in the answer, I just edited it